# Can't get Gutenberg InspectorControls to work

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I try to create a block and I wanna use the InspectorControls, but I can't get it to work. I know its deprecations/moved to wp.components.* (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/backward-compatibility/deprecations/)

But if is use it like that, its still not working.
I tried the following:

```
InspectorControls = wp.editor;
InspectorControls = wp.editor.InspectorControls;
InspectorControls = wp.blocks;
InspectorControls = wp.blocks.InspectorControls;
InspectorControls = wp.components;
InspectorControls = wp.components.InspectorControls;
```

This is my code:

```
let el = wp.element.createElement,
    registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType,
    ServerSideRender = wp.components.ServerSideRender,
    TextControl = wp.components.TextControl,
    TextareaControl = wp.components.TextareaControl,
    InspectorControls = wp.editor;

registerBlockType( 'mir-shortcodes-plugin/msc-rotating-icon-circle', {
    title: 'Rotating icon circle',
    category: 'msc-shortcodes',

    attributes: {
        'icon': {
            type: 'string',
            default: "arrows-alt"
        },
        'icon_style': {
            type: 'string',
            default: "fas"
        }
    },

    edit: (props) => {

        if(props.isSelected){
            // do something...
            //console.debug(props.attributes);
        };

        return [
            /**
             * Server side render
             */
            el("div", {
                    className: "mb-editor-container",
                    style: {textAlign: "center"}
                },
                el( ServerSideRender, {
                    block: 'mir-shortcodes-plugin/msc-rotating-icon-circle',
                    attributes: props.attributes
                } )
            ),

            /**
             * Inspector
             */
            el( InspectorControls,
                {}, [
                    el( "hr", {
                        style: {marginTop:20}
                    }),

                    el( TextControl, {
                        label: 'Icon',
                        value: props.attributes.icon,
                        onChange: ( value ) => {
                            props.setAttributes( { icon: value } );
                        }
                    } ),

                    el( TextControl, {
                        label: 'Icon color',
                        value: props.attributes.icon_color,
                        onChange: ( value ) => {
                            props.setAttributes( { icon_color: value } );
                        }
                    } ),
                ]
            )
        ]
    },

    save: () => {
        /** this is resolved server side */
        return null
    }
} );
```

Error Log:

```
[Error] Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `edit`.
    in edit (created by Edit)
    in Edit (created by WithToolbarControls(Edit))
    in WithToolbarControls(Edit) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))
    in Unknown (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(Component) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))) (created by WithFilters(Edit))
    in WithFilters(Edit) (created by BlockEdit)
    in BlockEdit (created by HoverArea)
    in BlockCrashBoundary (created by HoverArea)
    in div (created by IgnoreNestedEvents)
    in IgnoreNestedEvents (created by ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents))
    in ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents) (created by HoverArea)
    in div (created by HoverArea)
    in div (created by IgnoreNestedEvents)
    in IgnoreNestedEvents (created by ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents))
    in ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents) (created by HoverArea)
    in HoverArea (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(HoverArea) (created by BlockListBlock)
    in BlockListBlock
    in Unknown (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in (BlockListBlock) (created by WithFilters(BlockListBlock))
    in WithFilters(BlockListBlock) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock)) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock))) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock)))) (created by Pure(WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock))))))
    in Pure(WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock))))) (created by BlockList)
    in div (created by BlockList)
    in BlockList (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(BlockList) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(BlockList))
    in Unknown (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by CopyHandler)
    in CopyHandler (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(CopyHandler) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by ObserveTyping)
    in ObserveTyping (created by WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping))
    in WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping)) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping))) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by WritingFlow)
    in div (created by WritingFlow)
    in WritingFlow (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WritingFlow) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(WritingFlow)) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by BlockSelectionClearer)
    in BlockSelectionClearer (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer)) (created by VisualEditor)
    in VisualEditor (created by Layout)
    in div (created by Layout)
    in div (created by FocusReturnProvider)
    in FocusReturnProvider (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithViewportMatch(Layout) (created by NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)))
    in div (created by NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)))
    in NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout))) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)))) (created by Editor)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by Editor)
    in div (created by DropZoneProvider)
    in DropZoneProvider (created by BlockEditorProvider)
    in SlotFillProvider (created by BlockEditorProvider)
    in BlockEditorProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithRegistry(BlockEditorProvider) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WithRegistry(BlockEditorProvider)) (created by EditorProvider)
    in EditorProvider (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(EditorProvider) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(EditorProvider)) (created by Editor)
    in StrictMode (created by Editor)
    in Editor (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(Editor)
    warningWithoutStack (react.js:276)
    warning (react.js:1791)
    createElementWithValidation (react.js:3023)
    edit (index.js:74)
    renderWithHooks (react-dom.js:13027)
    mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.js:15109)
    performUnitOfWork (react-dom.js:19401)
    workLoop (react-dom.js:19441)
    renderRoot (react-dom.js:19524)
    performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.js:20431)
    performWork (react-dom.js:20343)
    performSyncWork (react-dom.js:20317)
    interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.js:20584)
    dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.js:4985)
    dispatchInteractiveEvent
[Error] Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `edit`.
    in edit (created by Edit)
    in Edit (created by WithToolbarControls(Edit))
    in WithToolbarControls(Edit) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))
    in Unknown (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(Component) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))) (created by WithFilters(Edit))
    in WithFilters(Edit) (created by BlockEdit)
    in BlockEdit (created by HoverArea)
    in BlockCrashBoundary (created by HoverArea)
    in div (created by IgnoreNestedEvents)
    in IgnoreNestedEvents (created by ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents))
    in ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents) (created by HoverArea)
    in div (created by HoverArea)
    in div (created by IgnoreNestedEvents)
    in IgnoreNestedEvents (created by ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents))
    in ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents) (created by HoverArea)
    in HoverArea (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(HoverArea) (created by BlockListBlock)
    in BlockListBlock
    in Unknown (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in (BlockListBlock) (created by WithFilters(BlockListBlock))
    in WithFilters(BlockListBlock) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock)) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock))) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock)))) (created by Pure(WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock))))))
    in Pure(WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock))))) (created by BlockList)
    in div (created by BlockList)
    in BlockList (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(BlockList) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(BlockList))
    in Unknown (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by CopyHandler)
    in CopyHandler (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(CopyHandler) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by ObserveTyping)
    in ObserveTyping (created by WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping))
    in WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping)) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping))) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by WritingFlow)
    in div (created by WritingFlow)
    in WritingFlow (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WritingFlow) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(WritingFlow)) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by BlockSelectionClearer)
    in BlockSelectionClearer (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer)) (created by VisualEditor)
    in VisualEditor (created by Layout)
    in div (created by Layout)
    in div (created by FocusReturnProvider)
    in FocusReturnProvider (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithViewportMatch(Layout) (created by NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)))
    in div (created by NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)))
    in NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout))) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)))) (created by Editor)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by Editor)
    in div (created by DropZoneProvider)
    in DropZoneProvider (created by BlockEditorProvider)
    in SlotFillProvider (created by BlockEditorProvider)
    in BlockEditorProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithRegistry(BlockEditorProvider) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WithRegistry(BlockEditorProvider)) (created by EditorProvider)
    in EditorProvider (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(EditorProvider) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(EditorProvider)) (created by Editor)
    in StrictMode (created by Editor)
    in Editor (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(Editor)
    warningWithoutStack (react.js:276)
    warning (react.js:1791)
    createElementWithValidation (react.js:3023)
    edit (index.js:74)
    renderWithHooks (react-dom.js:13027)
    mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.js:15109)
    performUnitOfWork (react-dom.js:19401)
    workLoop (react-dom.js:19441)
    callCallback (react-dom.js:143)
    dispatchEvent
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.js:193)
    invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.js:250)
    replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.js:18667)
    renderRoot (react-dom.js:19557)
    performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.js:20431)
    performWork (react-dom.js:20343)
    performSyncWork (react-dom.js:20317)
    interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.js:20584)
    dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.js:4985)
    dispatchInteractiveEvent
[Error] Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `edit`.
    invariant (react-dom.js:56)
    createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.js:10314)
    createFiberFromElement (react-dom.js:10335)
    createChild (react-dom.js:12114)
    reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.js:12365)
    reconcileChildren (react-dom.js:14491)
    mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.js:15153)
    performUnitOfWork (react-dom.js:19401)
    workLoop (react-dom.js:19441)
    callCallback (react-dom.js:143)
    dispatchEvent
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.js:193)
    invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.js:250)
    replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.js:18667)
    renderRoot (react-dom.js:19557)
    performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.js:20431)
    performWork (react-dom.js:20343)
    performSyncWork (react-dom.js:20317)
    interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.js:20584)
    dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.js:4985)
    dispatchInteractiveEvent
[Error] The above error occurred in the <edit> component:
    in edit (created by Edit)
    in Edit (created by WithToolbarControls(Edit))
    in WithToolbarControls(Edit) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))
    in Unknown (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(Component) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))) (created by WithFilters(Edit))
    in WithFilters(Edit) (created by BlockEdit)
    in BlockEdit (created by HoverArea)
    in BlockCrashBoundary (created by HoverArea)
    in div (created by IgnoreNestedEvents)
    in IgnoreNestedEvents (created by ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents))
    in ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents) (created by HoverArea)
    in div (created by HoverArea)
    in div (created by IgnoreNestedEvents)
    in IgnoreNestedEvents (created by ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents))
    in ForwardRef(IgnoreNestedEvents) (created by HoverArea)
    in HoverArea (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(HoverArea) (created by BlockListBlock)
    in BlockListBlock
    in Unknown (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in (BlockListBlock) (created by WithFilters(BlockListBlock))
    in WithFilters(BlockListBlock) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock)) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock))) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock)))) (created by Pure(WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock))))))
    in Pure(WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithFilters(BlockListBlock))))) (created by BlockList)
    in div (created by BlockList)
    in BlockList (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(BlockList) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(BlockList))
    in Unknown (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by CopyHandler)
    in CopyHandler (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(CopyHandler) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by ObserveTyping)
    in ObserveTyping (created by WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping))
    in WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping)) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping))) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by WritingFlow)
    in div (created by WritingFlow)
    in WritingFlow (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WritingFlow) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(WritingFlow)) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by BlockSelectionClearer)
    in BlockSelectionClearer (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer)) (created by VisualEditor)
    in VisualEditor (created by Layout)
    in div (created by Layout)
    in div (created by FocusReturnProvider)
    in FocusReturnProvider (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithViewportMatch(Layout) (created by NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)))
    in div (created by NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)))
    in NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout))) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(NavigateRegions(WithViewportMatch(Layout)))) (created by Editor)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by Editor)
    in div (created by DropZoneProvider)
    in DropZoneProvider (created by BlockEditorProvider)
    in SlotFillProvider (created by BlockEditorProvider)
    in BlockEditorProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithRegistry(BlockEditorProvider) (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(WithRegistry(BlockEditorProvider)) (created by EditorProvider)
    in EditorProvider (created by ComponentWithDispatch)
    in ComponentWithDispatch (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithDispatch(EditorProvider) (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(EditorProvider)) (created by Editor)
    in StrictMode (created by Editor)
    in Editor (created by ComponentWithSelect)
    in ComponentWithSelect (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithSelect(Editor)

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, BlockCrashBoundary.
    logCapturedError (react-dom.js:17206)
    logError (react-dom.js:17242)
    callback (react-dom.js:18183)
    callCallback (react-dom.js:16522)
    commitUpdateEffects (react-dom.js:16561)
    commitUpdateQueue (react-dom.js:16552)
    commitLifeCycles (react-dom.js:17453)
    commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.js:18825)
    callCallback (react-dom.js:143)
    dispatchEvent
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.js:193)
    invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.js:250)
    commitRoot (react-dom.js:19037)
    (anonyme Funktion) (react-dom.js:20507)
    unstable_runWithPriority (react.js:735)
    completeRoot (react-dom.js:20506)
    performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.js:20435)
    performWork (react-dom.js:20343)
    performSyncWork (react-dom.js:20317)
    interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.js:20584)
    dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.js:4985)
    dispatchInteractiveEvent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it... I just was missing to enqueue 'wp-editor'...

Here my example code:

```
wp_register_script(
                'mir-shortcodes-plugin-msc-rotating-icon-circle',
                plugins_url($index_js, __FILE__),
                array(
                    'wp-blocks',
                    'wp-i18n',
                    'wp-element',
                    'wp-components',
                    'wp-editor'
                ),
                filemtime("$dir/$index_js")
            );
```